# SQL Server data types to store strings and take less space

Tags: sql-server, database, string, varchar, nvarchar

I have a question in regards to data types that are available in SQL language to store data into the database itself. Since I'm dealing with database that is quite large, and has a tendency to expand over 150GB+ of data, I need to pay close attention and save up every bit of space on the server's hard drive so that the database doesn't takes up all the precious space. So my question is as following:

1. Which data type is the best to store 80-200 character long string in database?
2. I'm aware of for example `varchar(200)` and `nvarchar(200)` where the `nvarchar` supports unicode character. Which one of these would take up less space in database, or if there's a 3rd data type that I'm not aware of, and which I could use to store the data (if I know for a fact that the string I would store is just a combination of numbers and letters, without any special characters)
3. Are there some other techniques that I could use to save up space in database so that it doesn't expands rapidly ?

Can someone help me out with this ?

P.S. Guys, I have a 4th question as well:

4. If for example I have `nvarchar(max)` data type which is in a table, and the entered record takes up only 100 characters, how much data is reserved for that kind of record?
5. Let's say that I have ID which is of following form 191697193441 ... Would it make more sense to store this number as varchar(200) or bigint ?

Comment: `VARCHAR` takes 1 byte per character - `NVARCHAR` needs 2 bytes per character. A `nvarchar(max)` column which holds 100 characters will use 200 bytes (plus a little row overhead)

Comment: @marc_s excellent thanks for that =) And what about other data types? Are there other data types which would take up less space?

Comment: @marc_s can you see into my updated question ? I posted 4th question :)

Comment: `nvarchar` and `varchar` use 2 and 1 byte for each character respectively. If your column isn't going to need to store unicode characters,  then `varchar` is the correct choice, as it's half the size. It's also important to create a coloumn that has an appropriate data type. If you have a column that will only ever have up to 10 characters, but you declare it as a `varchar(100)` you've wasted 90 characters. Similarly, if you have a field that would only store the numbers between 1 and 100, then use `tinyint`.

Comment: For plain strings - **no** - those are your two choices, basically. If you have XML - store it as datatype `XML` since that type uses an optimized storage mechanism. In general: if something is **not** really a string (number, date), do **not** store it as string - use the most appropriate datatypes (these are typically using less storage than just strings)

Comment: @marc_s yes yes good point, I'll pay very close attention to that =)... So basically if something is nvarchar(max) and the stored data is nvarchar(100) let's say, how much space is then wasted?

Comment: The `(n)varchar` types will not **waste** any space - they store only what you really stick into them. If you have a `nvarchar(max)` (which holds up to 2 GB of data!), but you put 100 characters into it, it uses 200 bytes (+overhead). If you store only 5 characters in it, is uses 10 byte (+overhead)

Comment: @marc_s this is quite interesting. So let's say I have 1 million records in a table, storing nvarchar(80) would take up 160 bytes right ? and if I had used varchar(80), I would've actually had saved 80MB of space right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. So my take is: use `nvarchar` *only* if you really must support things like Unicode-alphabets - Hebrew, Cyrillic, Arabic, Far Eastern etc. - otherwise settle for `varchar`

Comment: @marc_s excellent I shall note that as the most important thing. Oh by the way. I have another question though, I'll update my initial question =)

Comment: @marc_s I 've updated my initial question with 5th one. Would it make more sense to store a 191697193441 number as varchar(200) or bigint in database?

Comment: @User987: Of course you should use integer types for integer values!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size needed for `nvarchar` is 2 bytes per character, as it represents unicode data. `varchar` needs 1 byte per character. The storage size is the actual number of characters entered + 2 bytes overhead. This is also true for `varchar(max)`.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql:

> varchar [ ( n | max ) ] Variable-length, non-Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes.

So for your 4th question, `nvarchar` would need 100 * 2 + 2 = 202 bytes, `varchar` would need 100 * 1 + 2 = 102 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

> There's no performance or data size difference as they're variable length data types, so they'll only use the space they need.

Think of the size parameter as more of a useful constraint. For e.g. if you have a surname field, you can reasonably expect 50 characters to be a sensible maximum size and you have more chance of a mistake (misuse of the field, incorrect data capture etc.) throwing an error, rather than adding nonsense to the database and needing future data cleansing.

So, my general rule of thumb is make them as large as the business requirements demand, but no larger. It's trivial to amend variable data sizes to a larger length in the future if requirements change.

Comment: Resizing is not trivial. And "modern" databases like Microsoft Azure SQL don't even let you choose anything smaller than `varchar(max)`, as it won't give any advantage.

Comment: @StefanM: at least for **SQL Server**, [it **definitely** makes sense to use **proper** length](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/whats-the-point-of-using-varchar(n)-anymore/) and not just `(n)varchar(max)` for everything!

Comment: Interesting site, thank you for the link. This seems to test for speed, not for size (which is irrelevant in this case). So yeah, if the given size is known, it most certainly is still true to choose that size for (n)varchar. It's still not available on Microsoft Azure SQL Databases. ;)